# How to turn off wireless network permanently in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, vaio

i'm using ubuntu 12.10 with win7 on sony vaio.
i want to turn off wireless network permanently in ubuntu just like "vaio smartnetwork" does in windows every time system boots.
please help.

Comment: If you really want to make it permanent then why not open the computer up and remove the wifi card? It's usually pretty easy, you just open an access port on the bottom, disconnect it, and slide it out. You won't break anything and you can always put it back in later.

Comment: @TomBrossman Sounds logical for people like us, but there a lot of computers that do not feature such a door or bay. Infact it is always better to look into the maintenance manual of the computer for such tasks. Unfortunately one has to search for them with a search engine because the marketing departments of the manufacturers can't get such trivial tasks as a simple product page done right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu we have command: rfkill which can turn off wireless devices. For example:

`rfkill list`

You will see something like this:

> 0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN    Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no
>
> 1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth  Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no
>
> 2: sony-wwan: Wireless WAN    Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no
>
> 3: phy0: Wireless LAN         Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no
>
> 4: hci0: Bluetooth            Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no

It means that all devices are working. If you want to block for example bluetooth type:

`rfkill block 4`

After that `rfkill list` will show

> 0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no
>
> 1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth   Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no
>
> 2: sony-wwan: Wireless WAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no
>
> 3: phy0: Wireless LAN          Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no
>
> 4: hci0: Bluetooth             Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: no

If you want to block all devices type: `rfkill block all` to unblock: `rfkill unblock all`

Answer (score 1):

Some firmwares (EFI/BIOS) provide an option to lock down several components individually, among them WiFi.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @msPeachy The user wants to turn off WiFi in Windows and Linux. Best choice is to do this at hardware level if possible, so this actually is a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a security issue or choice? If you click on the network icon, you can can turn off the option "enable networking" and "enable wireless". But you can turn them on the same way. I do not know how to manually turn it off so you can not turn it back on from the network icon.

Answer (score 0):

Install Jupiter and set wireless to off, next reboot, it will remain off, I do that to my bluetooth and touchpad and it works well.